# Editing header part in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am very new to Joomla and i am trying to edit some content in my [joomla site](http://irspaintingwe.com.au/) . in header of the site thier is some contact information

1. 1300 322 285

2.sal@irspainting.com.au

I am trying to edit these data from joomla backend , but i am unable to get where this data is coming .it look like hardcoded in backend .

I went with path libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php

But i didnt get any data .

can any one help me regarding this . sorry for my bad english

screenshot
[image: home positions]

Comment: What is version of your joomla ?

Comment: i am using joomla 3.3.3

Comment: What your are going to change in the header ?

Comment: phone numner and the email id

Comment: In the admin, Go to "Extensions " and select modules 
and look in Position like "top-header"

Comment: In the admin, Go to "Extensions " and select modules 
and look in Position like "top-left"
http://irspainting.com.au/?lang=en&tp=1

Comment: i have not found any module assign to position "top-header" , even i tried with "topbar-right" ,"topbar-left" and "logo-right" . nothing i have found

Comment: please search any custom html module in modules .

Comment: i have checked all the custom html modules , but i am not getting those information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must go to extensions menu and select modules item from dropdown menu. after that you must find a module with id "197" and open it for edditing.